# How do I express all Spanish Characters in vim regex？

Tags: vim

Today I am doing some text substitute work, but I find that `[a-z]` seems doesn't include Spanish characters like `ñ` or `á`. But in Spanish, they are just normal characters, not special symbols.

So, is there a way to include these characters in a simple vim regex phrase?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, Vim's regular expressions aren't very powerful in that respect. Atoms like `\a` and `[:alpha:]` only match ASCII characters.

You have to either explicitly include all special Spanish characters (`[a-záñ...]`), or use *equivalence classes*, which match while ignoring accents: `[[=a=][=b=][=c=]...]`